# Migrate VSS to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, vb6, visual-sourcesafe, vb6-migration

I have few project in VB6 and few are in VS.Net.
For VB6 we are using VSS for as version control and for VS.Net we are using TFS.
Now we are trying to use one version control that is TFS so we need to migrate VB 6 or VSS code into TFS.

Is there any way to use TFS for VB6 code or migrate ? 
We can't convert VB6 code VS.Net because few clients still using VB6 code.

Please advice if anyone has come across this situation or any experience to handle this situation.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I am using TFS version - 11.0.50727.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is more than one question, so let's take them separately.

### Use TFS from VB6

You must install the proper client for TFS: this is explained in detail on [Jesse's post](https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-connect-any-visual-studio-version/).
Shortly, you must install the 32-bit MSSCCI provider, the only supported by VB6.

### VSS Migration

There is a tool that helps you import your source code with history and permission in TFS ([Visual Source Safe Upgrade Tool for Team Foundation Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EdH-MSFT.VisualSourceSafeUpgradeToolforTeamFoundationServer)). It will not do anything to your VB6 projects: they will be intact.

In my opinion this is an optional step, as you can simply create a new repo in TFS can commit the code there (after fixing the binding as explained later) and leave your old VSS repository in read-only mode (by removing write permissions from users).

### VB6 bindings

VB6 projects now in TFS still remember VSS.
To unbind the VB project from VSS, you have to delete the `vssver.scc` and `mssccprj.scc` files.